# Track each screen view duration with additional parameters

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, flurry, localytics

I want to track the time spent by the user on each screen in my android app with additional parameters specific to that screen. I have explored:

[Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens), [CleverTap](http://clevertap.com), [Localytics](https://www.localytics.com) all of them allow me to record session timing for each screen but does not have the facility of adding additional parameters to it and later out filtering the result based on those additional parameters.

[Flurry](http://flurry.com) allows me to track event along with event duration but again does not allow me filter the result based on those additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With CleverTap, you can raise a screen viewed event with a bunch of properties. You could also create a segment of users based on the property values in the "screen viewed" event. Operators supported are equals, not equals and contains. You can then filter any funnel, cohorts, user action by this user segment.

The time taken by users in each screen is automatically tracked and displayed in the funnel report. You don't have to track it separately.

Comment: I integrated clevertap in the app, could not find session duration anywhere.

Comment: It's available on the funnel report page, where if you add the steps it'll show you the time spent in aggregate by users between each step.